# Rearranging items in Windows 8.1 Navigation pane

Tags: windows-explorer, navigation, windows-8.1-preview

Is it possible to rearrange items in the Navigation pane of File Explorer in the Windows 8.1 Preview?

Currently it shows Favorites, SkyDrive, This PC, and Libraries (from top to bottom), but I would rather have them arranged just like I had it before in Windows 7 - Favorites, Libraries, Computer (or This PC).

Any clues?

Comment: Showing/hiding options is generally possible, but rearranging might be difficult. Perhaps some third-party utility exists to do this...

Comment: Finding it may be a quest, huh? :)

Comment: Sure, and I wish you luck on your journey! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No real fix for this, but you could try pinning Libraries and C: drive ect, to your favourites, then they will always stay on top of the list. It just a temp fix thats working for me.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to move Libraries to below Favorites... http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-move-libraries-above-this-pc-in-windows-8-1/.
I hate having SkyDrive and Homegroup before Computer though so any fix for that would be nice...

1. Open the Registry editor `regedit`.
2. Go to the following key:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}`

3. You will see the **SortOrderIndex** value which is set to **84** (in decimals). Change it to **56** in decimals.
4. Libraries will now appear directly below Favorites, above This PC, Network, etc. in Windows 8.1

Comment: Please describe the method because links can often end up being broken.

Comment: @Benjamin I edited your answer to include the instructions from the link you provided. Just in case the link goes down. It worked for me.

Comment: You can do the same with OneDrive, DropBox etc For me, i had File Explorer opened while changing the decimal value of the mentioned Navigation pane items and the effect was seen on value change. I wanted to have OneDrive and DropBox at the end of the list, so I just changed to value to 90 and 92. Not sure if that will in any way compromise anything, but for now it works! Oh, if one wishes to acomplish the same thing, I simply searched for OneDrive, DropBox reg entry with SortOrderIndex REG_DWORD. Tested on win 10. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in Windows 8.1 till now to rearrange items in navigation pane, but this might change with the final release.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that will work for Libraries:
Close all explorer windows, and backup the registry (recommended).
Choose a node group to swap OneDrive with and Google the CLSID. I chose Libraries.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5} (for 64 bit)
```

Make a record of the SortOrderIndex value (mine was 54)
Also make a record of the SortOrderIndex value for the OneDrive CLSID (mine was 42)

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{8E74D236-7F35-4720-B138-1FED0B85EA75}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{8E74D236-7F35-4720-B138-1FED0B85EA75} (for 64 bit)
```

You may be required to modify administrative privileges on Libraries by right clicking the LH node and modifying the permissions dialogue.
On the RH pane change the Libraries SortOrderIndex value to 42 (dec) only, do not swap the SortOrderIndex values (it will do this for you and you may not need extra permissions for this). Open an explorer window to view the changes.

"This PC" {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} did not have a SortOrderIndex value on this machine, it may work if given one.
I will consider doing a Batch/Powershell script for this.

More CLSIDs can be found [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13591-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-8-a.html) and add folders to a library [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows7/include-folders-in-a-library).